# Clarification for Extension Fields and Galois Field

Tags: finite-fields, extension-field

I just need some help understand what an extension field is.

We know $[Q{(\sqrt2}):Q]=2$

Is this the same as saying what is the degree of the min. monic polynomial $p(x)\in Q[x]$ s.t $p(\sqrt2)=0$. Does this same reasoning work for the problem below?

$f(x)\in GF(p)$ where $\deg f(x)=k$ and $x(x^ {p^{n-1}}-1)\in GF(p)$

Then the finite extension $[GF(p)(\alpha):GF(p)]=k$ as $f(\alpha)=0$ where $f(x)\in GF(p)$ with $\deg f(x)=k$

Thank you for the help

Comment: You seem to have a lot of confusion about polynomials over finite fields. If we are considering polynomials in $x$ over the finite field $GF(p)$, then the ring of all such things is $GF(p)[x]$. We never have $f(x) \in GF(p)$ unless $f$ is a constant polynomial. In particular, $x(x^{p^{n-1}} - 1) \notin GF(p)$.

Comment: We can have $f(x)\in GF(p)[x]$ though correct?

Comment: And $(x^ {p^{n}}-x)\in GF(p)[x]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what all the $G(p)$ and $GF(p)$ are, but it is true that for any field $K$ and $\alpha$ algebraic over $K$, the degree of the extension $[K(\alpha):K]$ equals the degree $k$ of the minimal polynomial $f$ of $\alpha$.

This is because of the definition of a minimal polynomial, which implies that $1, \alpha, \alpha^2,\ldots,\alpha^{k-2}, \alpha^{k-1}$ are all linearly independent over $K$ (otherwise $f$ wouldn't be minimal), but $\alpha^k$ lies in their span (because $f(\alpha)= 0$, which  may be rearranged into $\alpha^k = \cdots$).

Comment: For something like $[F(a)(b):F]$, where $f(a)=0$ for some $f(x)\in F[x]$ and similarly for $b$ and $g(x)\in F[x]$, what is the degree of this extension field?
$[F(a)(b):F]=[F(a)(b):F(a)][F(a):F]=(deg g(x))(deg f(x))$?

Comment: @Stack That really depends. It clearly can't be larger than $(\deg f)(\deg g)$ (by an argument very much like the above), but it can, in some cases, be smaller. For instance, if $F = \Bbb Q$, $a = \sqrt 2$ and $b = \sqrt[4]2$, where $\deg f = 2, \deg g = 4$ and $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2, \sqrt[4]2):\Bbb Q] = 4$.